# inline elements direction

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change inline element order using only css?

Like we have this:

```
<span class="opening_quote">“</span>
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum...</span>
<span class="closing_quote">”</span>
```

- Text will be multi-line.
- Code should support ie6+ so :after and :before we can't use.

But for rtl direction we should change order of quotes and text:

```
“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit”
```

to

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur”
                        “adipiscing elit
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the following structure:

```
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum...</span>
<span class="opening_quote">“</span>
<span class="closing_quote">”</span>
```

And add `absolute` to quotes depends on the direction.

Comment: That's perfect, I'll use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could combine text-align (as was already suggested) on the `.text` `span` with changing the `float` on `.opening_quote` so it floats right when needed or change it's position to `absolute` with `right: 0;`

Answer (score -1):

There is a CSS `direction` property which when applied to a parent element should fulfill your needs. [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/direction)

```
<style>
.rtl {direction:rtl;}
</style>

<p class="rtl">
<span class="opening_quote">“</span>
<span class="text">Lorem ipsum...</span>
<span class="closing_quote">”</span>
</p>
```

[See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Thttg/)

Comment: No, sorry, it does not change elements order.

Comment: Look at your quotes in the second part: they look at wrong ways.